# How to print substring containing time stamp in the format 'day dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss.ms' from string using select-string pattern of regex expression?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to print substring from string with timestamp having format *"day dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss.ms"* .

For instance

*"Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84 Updated drivers successfully"*

I want to get only timestamp part of the line.  How to achieve this using regex expression and select-string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff`?

Since that format produces a fixed-length output (I think - the [date separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator) and [time separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator) are of type `String`, so they could conceivably be multiple `Char`s long, although accommodating culture-specific separators would be tricky with regex, too) you could just extract the timestamp from the first 26 characters...

```bsh
PS> $text = 'Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84 Updated drivers successfully'
PS> $timestampText = $text.Substring(0, 26)
PS> $timestamp = [DateTime]::ParseExact($timestampText, 'ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff', $null)
PS> $timestampText, $timestamp
Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84

Thursday, May 12, 2016 12:11:14 PM
```

Otherwise you could use a regex like this...

```bsh
PS> $text = 'Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84 Updated drivers successfully'
PS> $pattern = '^[a-z]{3}\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}'
PS> $format = 'ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff'
PS> if ($text -match $pattern) { $Matches[0]; [DateTime]::ParseExact($Matches[0], $format, $null) }
Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84

Thursday, May 12, 2016 12:11:14 PM
```

I used `\s+` for the two spaces...just because, but you could also use a literal space instead.

You could also eliminate the repetitive `\d{2}/\d{2}/` and `\d{2}:\d{2}:` in the pattern with...

```bsh
PS> $pattern = '^[a-z]{3}\s+(?:\d{2}/){2}\d{4}\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{2}'
```

Inspired by [@Vishal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59368969/150605) to extract everything before the third space, you could retrieve that one of two ways...

```bsh
PS> $text = 'Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84 Updated drivers successfully'
PS> ($text -split ' ', 4 | Select-Object -First 3) -join ' '
Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84
PS> if ($text -match '^\S+ \S+ \S+') { $Matches[0] }
Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84
```

Comment: Thank you @BACON, the desired output was obtained

Answer (score 1):

```
Set-Variable -Name "TEST" -Value "Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84 Updated drivers successfully"

$Timestamp = $TEST.Split(" ")[0,1,2]

Write-Host $Timestamp



Thu 12/05/2016 12:11:14.84
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that.  +1.  "Everything before the third space" might be more resilient than a fixed character offset.  That could be obtained with `($text -split ' ', 4 | Select-Object -First 3) -join ' '` or `$text -match '^\S+ \S+ \S+'`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the substring time stamp do this:

```
"The string" -match "..[:]..[:]..[.].."
$matches[0]
```

Comment: The answer which you provided is uncertain. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: It displays dd:hh:mm.ms" format. How can we get complete "day dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms"?